# ggplot function with only the septum of color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm practicing `ggplot` for data visualization.
However, when I apply the code as follow:

```
> ggplot(halloweenn,aes(x=Time,y=Count,color=Date,group=Date))+ geom_point()
```

The scatter plot show like this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z2D9.png

The unit of year becomes 2 and the color is super difficult to check. This is very different from the sample that I saw online and from my teacher, their plots are in different color and the unit of the year remain 1 as my original data.

Is there anything wrong with my code or what should specify in order to the scatter I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `color = factor(Date)` so ggplot doesn't treat it as a numerical variable

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself.
The type of `Date` and `Time` here is `class` rather than `factor`.
After converting the data type, the scatter plot has the same outcome I want.

Comment: I don't think there are `class` type of vectors in R. Usually the `class` is an attribute of some structure indicating S3 object-oriented classes.